# Mounting Quartz slab on drywall or cement

Tags: drywall, mounting, granite, quartz

I am thinking of mounting a quartz slab (*3/4" thick*) that extends to the ceiling behind my 36" range top and range hood (*chimney style*).

I was wondering if it is secure enough to mount it on drywall, or should I use a cement board behind the quartz slab.

Below is a picture of approximately where I am mounting the quartz (*vertical drywall*).

[image]

Comment: Your setup plan for the back splash is identical to what was just done in my kitchen.  Mine only went from just below the countertop to the ceiling and the mounting surface was drywall.

Comment: @Alaska ahhh ok perfect, I was just worried it couldn't hold onto the drywall and it will fall off ;)